# Firebase manual UTM attribution

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

Can I expect traffic_source.* fields to be populated in my BigQuery export of Firebase events, if I don’t use dynamic links, but instead manually provide:

- `utm_source` (for `traffic_source.source`)
- `utm_medium` (for `traffic_source.medium`)
- `utm_campaign` (for `traffic_source.name`)

in the url when a user lands on the page.
The platform is Web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, checked myself, the export works!